# Enter comment on enter key

Tags: youtube, user-interface, userscripts

I want to be able to type YouTube comments and replies and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the message.

At the moment, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a new line. I find this useless as I never use newlines in my comments.

How can I re-configure YouTube to be able to submit YouTube comments and replies with an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress?

Comment: Doesn't look like there's an existing user script for this, but you could probably make one pretty easily. Add an event handler to the comment box (by class, probably) to listen for Enter, then trigger the submit.

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button twice and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to post a comment/reply. I hope they make an option for disabling/enabling submission of comment/reply with a keypress...

Comment: hehehe... i was just new